# Is there a way to tell if EEPROM on an arduino has ran out of reads and writes?

Tags: arduino

You can only read and write to an arduino's memory about 100,000 times. I was wondering if there was a proper way of testing if an Arduino has run out of reads and writes to its internal memory other then it just not saving anything.  I just want to be sure that's whats happening before I buy a new one.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the quote, "measurement changes state", you must first waste a write to prove you can read it back correctly.

Erasing a cell is setting all bits to 1, so you could write 0x00, check all bits are what you expect, then write 0xFF completing a full cycle. If the cell has 'cleared' to 0xFF then the cell is still good. However there is no guarantee the next write will work when you put your actual data in it.

Keeping track of the state of each cell/block and verifying the contents on write is part of what would typically be implemented in a wear leveling routine, and would allow you to provide data integrity for as long as possible.